# Create new user session without password in authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, omniauth

I am using authlogic and omniauth for authentication in my Rails 3.0.10 app. 
However when I get the callback from the omniauth provider,  I am not able to create a new user session so as to sign in the user.

In [other responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730143/authlogic-create-new-session-without-password) (and even in the [authlogic docs](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)), it says that using `UserSession.create(@user, true)` should be able to create and persist a new session.

However, this does not work for me. It only works if the `@user` has a password in the database (by inserting a password directly in the db).

But there is no password when using third-party authentication providers, hence I cannot sign in users.

Any ideas how to sign in a user without a password in authlogic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `User` model:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  external = Proc.new { |r| r.externally_authenticated? }

  config.merge_validates_confirmation_of_password_field_options(:unless => external)
  config.merge_validates_length_of_password_confirmation_field_options(:unless => external)
  config.merge_validates_length_of_password_field_options(:unless => external)
end
```

`externally_authenticated?` is just a method on the user that checks what is providing the user information, and if it's one of the omniauth providers, returns true.

Comment: How are you checking for whether or not the user is authenticated via omniauth or not? i.e. what are you using for `externally_authenticated?`

Comment: It did not work for me to declare external in the config and pass it as an option. I had to pass in `externally_authenticated?` itself as the option for it to work. The method implementation is a one-liner `!authentications.empty? or password.blank?`